# Is it possible to introduce (banding, moire and other effects) on a presented video that makes it impossible to capture with an iPhone?

Tags: video-processing, video

an absolute noob here, so possibly a silly question.

I wonder if it's possible through video editing, to purposefully induce screen capture distortion effects on a video to such an extent that when presented on a monitor/laptop/projector, it makes capturing a clear photo or video of the content using an iPhone nearly impossible, while still remaining intelligible to the naked eye (without causing seizures).

A bit of background. I recently attended a conference and used my iPhone 13 to take some Live Photos of the presented slides. While visually I could see the presented material without any issue, my iPhone photos had all sorts of distortions that made it difficult to read the content. I was surprised that my iPhone was stumped by a simple projector's refresh rate.

Now I'm curious, is it possible to use video editing to purposefully induce these effects?
e.g. Could I edit video of a slide presentation so that if I were to take a photo of the content that is presented on my MacBook 2014 Retina display, or my Dell 1080 60FPS monitor the captured photos or video would be too distorted for me to read, while the original content would still be visually intelligible to my naked eye.

I've tried to do research, but I've never seen anything exploring how to induce, not reduce, these distortions.

Thanks for the help, hopefully it's an interesting question[image]

Comment: the effect you're looking for is called "rolling shutter" effect and looking at the picture, my guess would be that this was a laser projector